# Device Tree Overlay for HX8357 Driver

Tags: linux, arm, device, embedded-linux, device-driver

I am looking for a Device Tree Overlay (.dts) for the hx8357 for the Raspberry Pi. I am trying to make sure that I properly configure the display.

I have looked here: https://github.com/notro/fbtft/tree/master/dts/overlays/rpi

The overlay would be for this display: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2097

Comment: Why not write and compile one yourself?

Comment: I am writing one myself. I wanted to look at one for this device to make sure that I initialize the driver correctly. Many device tree nodes require an init property that initializes the device. This information requires some knowledge of the device itself. An already existing overlay would contain this.

Comment: So what I did was rip the Device Tree from the .dtb in the Ada Fruit GitHub and gave it a long slow gaze. It was very helpful because there are not any examples for the HX8357 Driver. I learned how to define the SPI I/O and I am sorting out the GPIO stuff.